# How to control Chrome browser from an NUnit test?

Tags: automation, nunit, google-chrome

What is the easiest way to control Chrome (pc/mac) from an NUnit test?

Things I want it to do:

- Use a proxy server I specify
- not bring up any dialog boxes that need to be clicked.
- open a url I specify
- close

With firefox I can do all these things by writing out a temp firefox profile, and telling firefox to use it.  If someone knows an answer to this question for IE, I'd also love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Watin doesn't seem to let me specify which proxyserver the browser in question should connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Watir to do this:
http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-proxies/

Unfortunately I don't know if you can use Watir from Ironruby to make this work in an NUnit test without having to many ruby dependencies.